# Rally sdk - get list of tasks from a story object

Tags: sdk, rally

Know how to get list of tasks from a Rally story object? The Tasks is list in story. I tried with story.get("Tasks") and story.getCollection("Tasks"). But both the methods throw undefined error in debugger

```
    Ext.Array.each(stories, function(story){
        var storyTasks = ***story.get('Tasks');***

        storyTasks.load({
            fetch: ['Owner', 'FormattedID'],
            callback: function(records, operation, success){
                Ext.Array.each(records, function(record){
                    taskOwners.push({owner: record.get('Owner'),
                        points: story.PlanEstimate});
                }, this);
            },
            scope: this
        });         
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a really nice example of how to do this in the docs:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2-section-collection-fetching

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that does it with promises:

```
launch: function() {
        var stories = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
            model: 'UserStory',
            fetch: ['Tasks']
        });
        stories.load().then({
            success: this.loadTasks,
            scope: this
        }).then({
            success: function() {
                //great success!
            },
            failure: function(error) {
                //oh noes!
            }
        });
    },

    loadTasks: function(stories) {
        var promises = [];
        _.each(stories, function(story) {
            var tasks = story.get('Tasks');
            if(tasks.Count > 0) {
                tasks.store = story.getCollection('Tasks');
                promises.push(tasks.store.load());
            }
        });
        return Deft.Promise.all(promises);
    }
```